# How to create selector, that link to dynamically created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know, how to create selector, that links to dynamically created element, without using event on the dynamically created element?

NOTE: dynamically created element I mean element, that is not in HTML at the beginning

I know that I can use $(this), when I have event (for example .click) on the element, but when I don't have event and I need selector on the dynamically created element?

Thanks to all.

update: Here is my situation:

```
$(".product div a").click(function() {
            var nameOfProduct = $(this).parent().find("h3").text();
            var dataPrice = parseInt($(this).parent().find("div b").text());
            var isProductIn = false;
            var itemsInDay = $(/*HERE I NEED THE SELECTOR*/).find("div.item").nextUntil("div.center");

            itemsInDay.each(function () {
                if (nameOfProduct == ($(this).find("span ins span").text())) {isProductIn = true;};
            });

            if (isProductIn) {
                //add only +1, not new product again;
            } else {
                var imgOfProduct = $(this).parent().parent().find("img").attr('src').replace('med', 'min');
                var product = ('<div class="item" data-price="' + dataPrice + '"><img src="' + imgOfProduct + '"><span><ins><b>1x</b> ' + nameOfProduct + '</ins><a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png"></a></span></div>');
                $(product).appendTo(".dayOrder:last").delay(800).hide().slideDown();
            }
            return false;
});
```

Comment: How do you create dynamically created element? Some code?

Comment: assign a variable to the element when you're creating it and then you can keep using that to manipulate the element.

Comment: Why would you need this kind of behaviour? You'd have better to tell what are you looking for, why would you need 'dynamic' selector?!

Comment: you can select every thing. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Add some code you question is barely readable.

Comment: `$(/*HERE I NEED THE SELECTOR*/)` Which selector are you talking about? Your posted code makes your question more unclear to me. You'd have better to provide a minimalistic jsfiddle which replicates your issue, maybe someone could understand what you are talking about because obviously no one undertand it actually

Comment: itemsInDay is "array" of divs, that I have to browse, because I need get to know, if the product already exists in list. The selector I am talking about helps me to point at the list of products, that were dynamically created.

Comment: list of products doesnt exists at the beginning ... list of product is created in "else branch"

Comment: You need to target elements before appending it to the DOM? So why not define variable once elements are added? I said define, not declare. Anyway, this doesn't really make any sense without seeing why would you need that

Comment: Eshop - When someone click on the product, I need to add product into basket. But when product already exists in the basket, All I need is increase number of products (+1), without addition whole product again.

Comment: @A.Wolff I am trying define variable once elements are added, but without succes. It says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined. Could you write the code to my situation please?

Answer (score 1):

Try something lihe this http://jsfiddle.net/pEb7D/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
dynamicSelector = $('.test').append('<div class="newElement">Hello!</div>');

setTimeout(function () {
    dynamicSelector.text('Goodbye!');
}, 3000);
```

UPDATE:
OK, so you're putting the items into the `.orderDay:last` element.  There you could loop through it's contents and see if you already have an existing element of one or other type.

However I would recommend making an array according to the product ID and then reacting to that.
For example http://jsfiddle.net/8byQp/

Javascript:

```
daysOrderArray = [];    
$(".product div a").click(function() {
            var nameOfProduct = $(this).parent().find("h3").text();            
            var imgOfProduct = $(this).parent().parent().find("img").attr('src').replace('med', 'min');
            var dataId = $(this).parent().parent().data("id");
            var dataPrice = parseInt($(this).parent().find("div b").text());
            priceSum += dataPrice;
            updatePrice(priceSum);

            if(dataId in daysOrderArray){
                // Now add number rather than new product.
                daysOrderArray[dataId]++;
                $('.item[data-id="' + dataId + '"] .quantity').text(daysOrderArray[dataId]);

            } else {
                daysOrderArray[dataId] = 1;
            var product = ('<div class="item" data-id="' + dataId + '" data-price="' + dataPrice + '"><img src="' + imgOfProduct + '"><span><ins><b><span class="quantity">1</span>x</b> ' + nameOfProduct + '</ins><a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png"></a></span></div>');
            $(product).appendTo(".dayOrder:last").delay(800).hide().slideDown();
            return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: +1 Let's see if this was it.

Comment: It maybe helps me, but could you write your advice specifically to my situation?

Comment: Can you write your question specifically to your situation.  I cannot see where the dynamically created element is, how it is created and I cannot see what html it is?

Comment: itemsInDay is "array" of divs, that I have to browse, because I need get to know, if the product already exists in list. The selector I am talking about helps me to point at the list of products, that were dynamically created. list of products doesnt exists at the beginning ... list of product is created in "else branch". Eshop - When someone click on the product, I need to add product into basket. But when product already exists in the basket, All I need is increase number of products (+1), without addition whole product again. webpage: http://www.checkitout.over.cz/objednej-si.html